# When to register for a bank account for a C-Corp with no official money

Tags: united-states, taxes, bank-account, small-business, incorporating

In Feb this year, I registered a C-Corp for administrative purposes only (for things that require a DUNS number, e.g., to get an Apple Enterprise Dev account, etc) and have thus far not passed any money officially through that entity.

As I understand, as long as the C-Corp doesn't have money passing through, I don't have to file taxes for it? Or, if I do, it's just filing 0's.

When would be a definitive point to sign up for a bank account for this c-corp? Should it be only when I'm ready to pass money through it?

If I set up a bank account for a C-Corp that might not have very much money go through it, how much more complicated would taxes such be?

Comment: How did your company get an Enterprise Dev Account if it never had any money?

Comment: You can pay using any payment source. DUNS number just requires a registered corporate entity.

Comment: You should always file tax return for corporations, regardless of activity

Answer (score 1):

Technically, it's only when you need to pass money through. However consider that the length the account has been open builds history with the financial institution, so I'd open ASAP. Longer history with the bank can help with getting approved for things like business credit lines, business cards, and other perks, though if you're not making money with that business, seek out a bank that does not charge money to have a business account open with them.

Comment: Most banks require a minimum deposit. If I put in a minimum deposit from my personal account, would I run into tax complications?

Comment: As a side note, Capital One Spark for Business-- https://www.capitalone.com/small-business-bank/ -- offers business accounts with no fees or minimum balances and is pretty light generally on paperwork.

Comment: anak - are you a spark user? what do you think? also what's the catch

Comment: @ina - formally, you, wearing your shareholder hat, would make a contribution to capital. The corporation would put that money in the bank.

Comment: @Pete Becker would that necessarily involve double taxation - i.e., i'm taxed for putting money into the corporation, and corp is taxed again for using it?

Comment: @ina - there's no income tax to the corporation on capital contributions. I think some states impose taxes based on total capitalization, but that's not common.